# Prove $x^n(x-y)(x-z)+y^n(y-x)(y-z)+z^n(z-x)(z-y)>0$

Tags: calculus, inequality, real-numbers

Let $x,y,z>0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, prove that:
$$x^n(x-y)(x-z)+y^n(y-x)(y-z)+z^n(z-x)(z-y)>0$$

Some idea? I have tried to develop the multiplication and certain assumptions buy I can't see it clearly. Note that this is not true if $x=y=z$ or $x=y=z=0$.

Comment: You might want to prove that $$x^n(x-y)(x-z)+y^n(y-x)(y-z)+z^n(z-x)(z-y)\color{red}{\geq}0$$

Comment: It's not true for $x=1,y=0,z=-2,n=1$.

Comment: Please check if the restriction $x,y,z>0$ is imposed.

Comment: @Dr.Mathva Is that true? The equality is trivial, but I'm not sure about de inequality.

Comment: @user The redaction is exactly the way I wrote, but maybe the teacher wrote it wrong because I can't find it in any book (I've found some excercises in Bartle's Introduction to Real Analysis)

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong. This restricts $x,y,z>0$.

Comment: "Note that this is not true if x=y=z".  Then it's not true.  You have to stipulate that the at least two of the terms are distinct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $\sum \limits_{cyc}x^t(x-y)(x-z) \geq 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2148756/prove-that-sum-limits-cycxtx-yx-z-geq-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume $x\ge y\ge z\gt0$. Then,
$$
\begin{align}
\Delta
&=x^n(x-y)(x-z)+y^n(y-x)(y-z)+z^n(z-x)(z-y)\\
&=\underbrace{\ (x-y)\ \vphantom{\left[y^n\right]}}_{x\ge y}\underbrace{\left[x^n(x-z)-y^n(y-z)\right]}_{\substack{x^n\ge y^n\ge0\quad x-z\ge y-z\ge0\\x^n(x-z)\ge y^n(y-z)}}+\underbrace{z^n(x-z)(y-z)\vphantom{\left[y^n\right]}}_{z^n\ge0\ \ x-z\ge0\ \ y-z\ge0}\\
&\ge0
\end{align}
$$
If $x=y\gt z$, then $\Delta=z^n(y-z)^2\gt0$.

If $x\gt y=z$, then $\Delta=x^n(x-y)^2\gt0$.

Thus, $\Delta=0$ only if $x=y=z$.

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong. Try $n=3$, $x=-1$ and $y=z=1$.

For positives variables it's true.

Indeed, let $x\geq y\geq z$.

Thus, $$\sum_{cyc}x^n(x-y)(x-y)\geq$$
$$\geq x^n(x-y)(x-z)+y^n(y-x)(y-z)=(x-y)(x^n(x-z)-y^n(y-z))\geq0$$
because $x^n\geq y^n$ and $x-z\geq y-z.$

By the same way we can prove the following inequality.

> Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be positive numbers and $t$ be a real number. Prove that:
>   $$x^t(x-y)(x-z)+y^t(y-x)(y-z)+z^t(z-x)(z-y)\geq0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Well.  It's *NOT* true.  If $x = y = z > 0$ then $x^n(x-y)(x-z) + y^n(y-x)(y-z) + z^n(z-x)(z-y) = 0$.

So you can *not* prove it.

But maybe we can prove it is we stipulate that at least two of the terms are distinct.

Note that we can label the three variables whatever we want and by symmetry we might as well, and we can assume without loss of generality that $0 < x \le y \le z$.  (we can just relabel the variables so that is true.)

Case 1:  $x=y < z$

Then $x^n(x-z)(x-y) + y^n(y-z)(y-x) + z^n(z-y)(z-x) = 0+0 + z^n(z-y)^2 > 0$ as $(z-y)^2 > 0, z^n > 0$.

Case 2: $x < y=z$

Then $x^n(x-y)(x-z) + y^n(y-z)(y-x) + z^n(z-x)(z-y) = x^n(x-y)^2 + 0 + 0> 0$ as $x^n, (x-y)^2 > 0$.

Case 3: $x < y < z$.

Then $x^n(x-y)(x-z) > 0$ and $y^n(y-z)(y-x) < 0$ and $z^n(z-x)(z-y) > 0$.

So we need to prove that $x^n(y-x)(z-x) + z^n(z-x)(z-y) > y^n(z-y)(y-x)$. (Note: all terms are positive.)

That will be true if and only if $\frac {x^n}{z-y} + \frac {z^2}{y-x} > \frac {y^n}{z-x}$

So it if we can prove: $\frac {x^n}{z-y} + \frac {z^2}{y-x} > \frac {y^n}{z-x}$ we will be done.

$z-y < z-x$ and $y-x < z-x$ so

$\frac {x^n}{z-y} + \frac {z^n}{y-x} >$

$ \frac {x^n}{z-x} + \frac{z^n}{z-x} > $

$\frac {z^n}{z-x} >$

$\frac {y^n}{z-x}$.

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Note that you have written down a slightly different version of [Schur's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_inequality):

- $x^t(x-y)(x-z)+y^t(y-x)(y-z)+z^t(z-x)(z-y) \color{red}{\geq} 0$ for $x,y,z \color{red}{\geq} 0$ and $t>0$

Equality holds iff $x=y=z$ or one of them is zero and the other two are equal.

A very simple proof of this inequality can also be found on the linked page.

Comment: This inequality is true for all reals $t$ and positive variables. See please my post. For $t<0$ we need to delete the first addend.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg : My intention here is to point out for the OP a well known result. To elaborate on the conditions to satisfy the "sharp" inequality I leave to the OP.